# How to account for data's margins of error in a regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, controlling-for-a-variable

Apologies if this is too simple of a question. I work with population data from the census, which provides a margin of error for all their variables. Reviewers have asked that I account for the MOE in census data but I'm not quite sure how to do that in a regression model. For example, in large census tracts, there can be quite large MOEs (e.g., estimate will be 500 households and the MOE could be 350) while in more dense areas the MOEs tend to be quite small (e.g., estimate 2000 households and the MOE of 100).

To account for MOEs do you transform the data or would you control for it on the right-hand-side of the equation? An example would be helpful too. Is the approach different in a machine learning model? Thank you!!

**Edit: Application example**

One example application is predicting the rate of renter eviction rate (eviction divided by the number of renters in a tract) based on neighborhood characteristics such as tract median rent, different racial group percentages, and income to name a few explanatory variables.

I would use a negative binomial model in this case given the variance and mean are not equal where the denominator is the offset, eviction counts are the true number of cases in a given tract, and the denominator for the response variable -- renters -- has an MOE. The other explanatory variables of rent, race percentages (a rate of the number of a relative race group divided by the number of renters), and income also have MOE's.

Comment: It depends on whether the MoEs apply to any explanatory variables or only to the response variables.  Weighted OLS handles the latter case. In the former case, what matters is the *relative magnitude* of each MoE within the context of the spread of the variable's values.  It also matters what you are attempting to do.  E.g., to predict the response based on the data, you don't care about the explanatory MoEs, but to obtain unbiased regression parameter estimates, you do care about them.  Thus, it would help to include more information about your application in this post.

Comment: Thanks @whuber, this is helpful. I also added an example.

Comment: Because you are using quotients of variables, the problem is even worse.  Consider downloading and using the [VRE Tables](https://www.census.gov/library/video/2020/calculating-margins-of-error-the-acs-way.html).  I would go beyond what the Census recommends and explore the distribution of the replicate results to assess whether it's meaningful to report an MoE for your result: sometimes the values are so skewed that the MoE alone is misleading.  The tough part is assessing the bias in using explanatory variables with large MoEs: you might need an errors-invariables procedure.